# Removing a phantom application

Tags: software-uninstall

I am a relatively new ubuntu user running 16.04 and I have a KeePass2 application that I believe I installed incorrectly and now I cannot figure out how to uninstall it. The application appears on my dash and I can run it but it just causes an icon to pop up for a couple of seconds and then disappears again.

I have used `sudo apt-get remove` and `sudo dpkg -l` and neither of them show any `keepass packages`. I also tried using `aptitude` and that does come up with a `keepass doc but for some reason I can not remove it with aptitude.

I don't really know what other information to give so if there is any other information you need please let me know.

Comment: How did you install that app, please post the commands you used and the steps followed

Comment: I'm sorry I have been ignoring the issue for awhile and so I don't remember exactly how I installed it. Is there any way to figure that out?

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up solving this problem relatively easily. First I needed to go to `~/.local/share/applications` and remove the .desktop file for KeePass. However the application was still showing up and so I checked the folder again and also looked through the wine directory. Sure enough inside of `~./local/share/applications/wine/Programs` there was a KeePass.destop file. After removing that file the application was finally removed from my dash!